# buffer pointer as argument in c function

Tags: c, buffer, arrays

In a my application (using c) i need to read some integer parameters from a byte buffer using this syntax:

```
param1 = (uInt16)(buffer[1]<<8) + buffer[0]);
param2 = (uInt16)(buffer[3]<<8) + buffer[2]);
```

I would like to write a function to get Integer from the buffer without using indexes or fixed number and calling it more times... like this:

```
param1 = getWord(buffer);  //The buffer now points to first integer
param2 = getWord(buffer);  //now the buffer points to second integer
```

In this case I need to pass the buffer as reference and for sure I need to increase the buffer pointer inside the function. Can someone help me to write this function? Probably I need to pass the array pointer as parameter but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Show your efforts and we wil help you in case of problems. This isn't a code for you service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: You could do it with a `static` variable, but I recommend to add a offset or index parameter `uint16_t getWord(uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t offset);`

Comment: @LPs Sorry, I know that is not a coding service, but I don't know how to pass the buffer reference in the function.. so I need a small help

Comment: `int getWord( char *buffer);` and call as you post.

Comment: @LPs yes but the buffer pointer doesn't change after the calling... the next parameter will use the same buffer .. I want to change the puffer pointer inside getWord

Comment: Ok. The use `int getWord( char **buffer);` and study how to use pointer to pointer.

Comment: @LPs ok , thanks I will check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 unsigned int getWord(*buffer)
{
    unsigned int a;
    a=((buffer[1]<<8)|buffer[0]);
    return a;
}
```

while operating use bitwise operators like '&', '|' not arithmatic operators like '+'

Hope u get the Idea

Comment: I can't use this because the pointer to buffer is every time the same... If I call this function more time I read the same value and not the next integer of the buffer. I need to modify the buffer pointer inside...

Comment: its a function, u can call it like    unsigned int a;    unsigned char array[]="Hello";     a=getWord(array);

Comment: the value of array can be changed and the function can be called again

Comment: In my case I read an array of byte from a memory (example 50 byte), Then I need to get data from the buffer (25 integer). I want to call 25 times the function getWord() to read the integers. With your function the buffer pointer  is every time the same. I can'r read the next integer after the first calling.

Comment: I updated the description. If I use your function I need to increase the buffer pointer in the calling probably using this: int a = getWord(*buffer+=2). My idea was to avoid to increase the point in the calling but inside the getWord() function... but probably your is the more easy solution..

Comment: create an arra of integers and put it in a loop, take another counter dat is incremented by 2 every time loop runs. this will become like a[i]=((buffer[j+1]<<8)|buffer[j]);   j=j+2; and i will be loop variable and return a;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107274/discussion-between-mukesh-and-lorenzo).